# Correct way to add variable and selectors to a not function - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, variables, jquery-selectors

I have checked a few answers on SO and I think my syntax is correct, but something is not working correctly.

I am trying to create an array of jquery selectors mixed with variables and store them in a not() function.

I have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/js5okk49/) to demonstrate.

The second line of the function is not working:

```
var trigger = $('mainNav li:eq(0) a');
var headerLinks = $('#header a').not('.control a', + trigger);
```

My first thought was that `#header a` has more precedence over `.control a` in css terms. But changing classes and ID's doesn't seem to work.

Similarly I have a simpler var further in my code:

```
var content = $('.content');
var added = $('.extraList', + content);
```

In the console `added` is only returning the `extraList` selector.

1 Does the not function work differently to other jquery selectors? I was hoping to see the array of all the elements selected and/or filtered in the console

2 Is there a way to store the vars and selectors in a standard array and call that? I don't know how this would look exactly as jquery would need to interpret it, but something like this:

```
var arr = ['.control a', headerLinks, content, '.post'];
```

I realise that is mixing types but I am not sure how to pass both jquery variables and selectors into the same array, if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Satpal. Your answer definitely helped me, but here is what I did.

Store an array of jquery selectors to later exclude from the function, I can keep adding to or edit this variable. (I think this is neater as it has separated out the code a little more and it circumvents the parent/child issue):

```
var exclude = $('#mainNav li:eq(0) a, .control a, .social-links a');
```

Create another set of links to include in the function:

```
var headerLinks = $('#header a');
var contentLinks = $('.post a');
```

Merge selectors which are going to be used to trigger the function and also add the excluded selectors:

```
var merge = $.merge(headerLinks, contentLinks).not(exclude);
```

Now the click function:

```
merge.on('click',function(){});
```

Should fire for the links that I want, and not the ones that I don't.

I would still like to know how to store an array of jquery selectors and variables in a standard javascript array.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/gk7bmzqh/1/

Answer (score 1):

For code `var headerLinks = $('#header a').not('.control a', + trigger);`

You can simply use chaing like

```
var headerLinks = $('#header a').not('.control a').not(trigger);
```

*OR*

```
var trigger = $('.control a, #mainNav li:eq(0) a'); //I am using here #mainNav
var headerLinks = $('#header a').not(trigger);
```

---

For `var added = $('.extraList', + content);`

You can use [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

> Create a new jQuery object with elements added to the set of matched elements.

```
var added = $('.extraList').add(content);
```

Comment: Thank you @Satpal I did try chaining the not functions but that did not seem to work. See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/js5okk49/4/

Comment: @lharby, `.control` is not child of `header` so `$('#header a').not('.control a')` will still refer to `$('#header a')`. what are you trying to acheive?

Comment: I am trying to populate a list of links that should not trigger a certain function. The other links that are not specified should trigger the function.

Comment: @lharby, see updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gk7bmzqh/ also instead of merge use `.add()`

Comment: OK well the add function works. Unfortunately the control a links are still logging 'was clicked' to the console when they should have been excluded. Ah OK,  not(): Remove elements from the set of matched elements. So it runs the first selector as the parent. Thank you.

Comment: @lharby, See http://jsfiddle.net/mbe547o7/ this will resolve your problem, main changes is `var headerLinks  = $('#header a').not(trigger);var contentLinks = $('.post a').not('.control a');`

Comment: Thanks, I will vote on this as it definitely helped me, but I am also going to post an answer also.